# Spring data rest how to secure only rest endpoints not repository methods

Tags: spring-security, spring-data-rest

For administrative reasons we are exposing some of our spring data repositories  via spring data rest.

Is there a way to protect the rest endpoints but not the repository methods?
The documentation only tells how to protect the repository.

Background

By protecting the repository with `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")` i ran into test errors.
Tests that use `saveAndFlush` told that no authentication was set in context but i set it with `@WithMockUser(roles = {"ADMIN"})` and this is working fine in all other tests.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of securing the repository, try to secure the endpoints in a WebSecurityConfigurer:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
      ...
      .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
      .and()
      ...
}
```